# Rails: HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many-through

I have problems with getting a `has_many through` association to work.

I keep getting this exception:

```
Article.find(1).warehouses.build
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :entries in model Article
```

These are the models involved:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :warehouses, :through => :entries
end

class Warehouse < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles, :through => :entries
end

class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :warehouse
end
```

And this is my schema:

```
create_table "articles", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "article_nr"
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "amount"
  t.string   "warehouse_nr"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "unit"
end

create_table "entries", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "warehouse_id"
  t.integer "article_id"
  t.integer "amount"
end

create_table "warehouses", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "warehouse_nr"
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "utilization"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Answer (score 117):

You need to add

```
has_many :entries
```

To each of your models, since the :through option just specifies a second association which it should use to find the other side.

Comment: you can also use **t.references :warehouse, :null => false** instead of **t.integer "warehouse_id"** in the create table relationship... more Rail-lish nowadays.

Comment: With this change I get `NameError: uninitialized constant Article::Entry`?

Answer (score 8):

You would need to add

```
has_many :entries
```

To each model, and above has_many :through, like this:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entries
  has_many :warehouses, :through => :entries
end

class Warehouse < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entries
  has_many :articles, :through => :entries
end
```

More detailed tutorial on how to handle view and controllers https://kolosek.com/rails-join-table/

Answer (score 2):

@Meekohi 
This means that you have no Entry model. I just received the error message myself, so wanted to point it out (can't post it as a comment due to low reputation).

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :warehouse
end
```

Simply run

```
rails g model Entry
```